# What is the difference between these headers?

Tags: angular, http, post, request-headers

I had an issue when using JWT Auth. After checking my code, I realized that the headers (containing bearer token) were not included when calling POST method. The header works perfectly on GET method but not on POST method.

I looked for an example and I realized that there is another way to "build" headers. I changed this and then it worked.

So, now I'm using one `httpOptions` for GET method and another for POST method.

This is my code. Note that I'm using `getHttpOptions` for "GET" and `postHttpOptions` for "POST".

```js
headers = new Headers();
getHttpOptions: any;
postHttpOptions: any;

constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    @Inject(APP_CONFIG) private config: AppConfig,
    private env: EnvService,
) {
    this.headers.append("Accept", "*/*");
    this.headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    this.headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + globals.user.Token);
    this.getHttpOptions = { headers: this.headers };

    this.postHttpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Accept': '*/*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + globals.user.Token,
        }),
    };
}
```

Calling when "GET":

```js
MyOtherFunction(User: string) {
    const url = this.env.apiUrl + `fantasy/world/` + User;
    return this.http.get(url, this.getHttpOptions)
        .pipe(map((response: Response) => response.json()));
}
```

Calling when "POST":

```js
MyFunction(operacion: any) {
    const url = this.env.apiUrl + `real/world`;

    return this.httpClient.post(url, operacion, this.postHttpOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[HttpHeaders](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders#append) is an immutable object. You can not modify it directly. Each method that makes a change returns a new instance of the object.

```js
    this.headers = this.headers.append("Accept", "*/*");
    this.headers = this.headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    this.headers = this.headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + globals.user.Token);
```

Documentation for `append()` reads:

> A clone of the HTTP header object with the value appended.

Comment: Thank you. I also check that I'm using "http.get" and  "httpClient.post"